# Community User change username/email

Tags: community

Is it possible to allow community users to change their Email/Username field?

I tried the following code which I execute as a logged in Community User;

```
final User user = [SELECT Email, Username FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
user.Email = 'new_email_here@example.com'; //this line will throw exception
user.CommunityNickname = 'new_email_here@example.com'; //but this line will work fine if we comment previous line
update user;
```

I got INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY exception. But if I only change CommunityNickname without Email - it works. Community User is able to change it's nickname, but not email.

What sort of permissions do I need?

Comment: Just as a workaround, you can execute this in Without sharing mode, and it will work. But if you are curious about permissions, I would rather recommend to describe user object and then its field to find permissions for community users. (I have already checked field accessibility and FLS for user object. Salesforce only shows that for custom fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more precise, execute following code from your community user's context

```
// Get the field describe result for the Name field on the Account object
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Schema.sObjectType.User.fields.Email;
system.debug(dfr.isUpdateable());

dfr = Schema.sObjectType.User.fields.communityNickName;
system.debug(dfr.isUpdateable());
```

This code snippet verifies that if Email and CommunityNickName are updatable by current logged in user.

You can check more details about a field permissions, using these methods : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm

Hope it helps.